Dialing and emergency number on android using kotlin and jetpack compose
I need to dial an emergency number from my app and from what I understand by reading the docs, I need to implement emergencyDial in IRadio.hal and implement emergencyDialResponse in IRadioResponse.hal to send a response with response type, serial number, and error information.
Doc reference for emergency number dialing
Doc reference for aidl
But I have never used HAL before and from what I researched, it is found in AIDL?
I've tried the answers from How can I call emergency number programmatically and tried the below:
with(Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)) {
                    data = Uri.parse("tel:${preCallUiState.service.main_contact}")
                    closeScreen()
                    activity.startActivity(this)
                }

and it doesn't work for emergency numbers such as 999.
Can someone help me understand how to get access to AIDL and implement this feature ?

Your documentation reference is for creating a custom build of Android, such as for your own custom hardware. It is unrelated to apps.

I rephrased and added the second doc that i was reading. Can you help me understand how to implement the IRadio.hal interface so that i can call the emergencyDial?

"I rephrased and added the second doc that i was reading" -- that does not change the fact that what you are describing has nothing to do with apps. "But I have never used HAL before and from what I researched, it is found in AIDL?" -- no. The hardware abstraction layer (HAL) is part of an operating system.

"Why does it have nothing to do with apps" -- the HAL is unrelated to app development. "i want to implement this feature in my app?" -- then you are going to need to use app techniques for attempting to dial an emergency number. If you want to modify a custom build of Android, such as for installing on your own custom hardware, then the HAL starts to come into play. From your question and comments, you do not seem to be creating a custom build of Android, and so the HAL is not part of the solution for your problem.

Okay i might've read this wrong. Then how can i perform an emergency dial ? Because right now if i use basic intent call, it doesn't work with emergency numbers

It it not supposed to be possible for ordinary apps to use ACTION_CALL for emergency numbers. That requires the CALL_PRIVILEGED permission, which is only available to system apps. The duplicate question covers several hacks, and I have no idea if they work.

I tried them and it does not work unfortunately. But thanks for helping

You may have to settle for ACTION_DIAL, then. Your only other alternative is to work with hardware partners to have your app be considered a system app.
